# Remove lines between 2 tags (with some constraints)

Tags: text-processing, sed

Input file is like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
Start
CCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDD
Stop
EEEEEEEEEEE
Stop
Rec
FFFFFFFFFFF
GGGGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHH
Start
IIIIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJJJ
Start
KKKKKKKKKKK
LLLLLLLLLLL
MMMMMMMMMMM
NNNNNNNNNNN
Stop
Rec
OOOOOOOOOOO
PPPPPPPPPPP
QQQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRRR
SSSSSSSSSSS
TTTTTTTTTTT
UUUUUUUUUUU
VVVVVVVVVVV
Start
WWWWWWWWWWW
XXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Desired output:

```
AAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
FFFFFFFFFFF
GGGGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHH
Start
IIIIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJJJ
OOOOOOOOOOO
PPPPPPPPPPP
QQQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRRR
SSSSSSSSSSS
TTTTTTTTTTT
UUUUUUUUUUU
VVVVVVVVVVV
Start
WWWWWWWWWWW
XXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

I want to remove all the lines between tags `Start` and tags `Stop\nRec` (tags included). The `Start`-`Stop\nRec` sequence can appear many times in a long file. `AAAAAA`, `BBBBBB`, `...ZZZZZZ` lines can be anything. The tags (`Start` and `Stop\nRec`) do not share their line with data (i.e. must be searched as `^tag$`. The end tag `Stop\nRec` has to be 2-lines tag.

But, when several `Start` are found before a `Stop\nRec` is found, the suppression must only apply from the last `Start` found before the `Stop\nRec` (in example, lines `IIIIIII` and `JJJJJJJ` are kept).

And, at the end of the file, when a `Start` tag is encountered but no `Stop\nRec` tag, the lines between this `Start` and the end of file must be kept (in example, lines `Start WWWWWW XXXXXX YYYYYY ZZZZZZ` are kept).

I want to do this rework with sed (running under bash shell on Linux) and using the -i option (same file for input and output).

I did the following, but it doesn't work properly (especialy when several Start tag are encoutered before a Stop\nRec tag is reached):

```
sed -i '/^Start\n/ {:a; $!{ N ; /\nStop\nRec$/!ba } s/.*// }' file.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can there be cases where `Rec` is not preceded by `Stop` or can we assume that `Rec` is a stop tag always?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
${H;x;p;q}
/Start/ {x;s/^\n//;p;d}
{H;N}
/Stop\nRec/ {s/.*//;h;d}
D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to test

```
sed '
    /Start/! b
    :a
    /\nStart$/{
        P
        D
    }
    N
    $b
    /Stop\nRec/! ba
    d
' Input.file
```